# Replacing the same string of text with other unique strings of text

Tags: javascript

I have the string "I love you, because you're funny" and have another 700 good attributes. Now, instead of putting those into the "I love you, because" format by hand, I want to write code that takes those 700 attributes, and makes a "I love you, because" sentence with each of it.

I have no idea how to do something like this, but I thought this'd be easy for most people here. Help is much appreciated!

This is what I have:

```
['funny', 'generous', 'smart'].map(s => `I love you, because you are ${s}`)
```

but I don't know how to let a program spit out the phrases, that I then can copy.

Problem resolved, thanks so much guys!

Comment: Voting to close as incomplete, but since it's such a sweet thought: `['funny', 'generous', 'smart'].map(s => \`I love you, because you are ${s}\`)`

Comment: Hi danh, thank you so much for the answer. I don't (evidently) know how to code, so where would I put the code that you gave me for it to spit out what I want? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Much depends on where you want to have the results

Comment: Just somewhere where I can then copy the text from

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems you need further guidance.
Below is a working example with comments to explain what each part does

```js
// Array of attributes you want to have in each message
var loveMessageAttrinute = [
  "funny",
  "strong"
]

// The container you want to put this messages in
var loveMessageContainer = document.getElementById("LoveMessages");

// for each attribute in your array get on attribute at a time
// it will first get "funny" then after it appends and add the message to the container it gets the next attribute "strong" and so on
loveMessageAttrinute.forEach((attr) => {
  // append the attribute to the message
  var message = `<p>I love you because you are ${attr}<p/>`
  // put the message to the container 
  loveMessageContainer.innerHTML += message;
});
```

```html
<div id="LoveMessages">
</div>
```